# Looking for a fanfic in which Tom creates the Diary horcrux and Harry Potter appears

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

It starts out with Tom creating the Diary Horcrux in the middle of the CoS, and as he is finishing the ritual, a severely injured/dying Harry appears, holding the Diary. The Diary refuses to be taken away from Harry, and waves its pages around. Tom tells the basilisk to keep an eye on Harry (whom Tom does not know), and inform him through the pipes if anything happens. The basilisk tells Tom that it failed, Harry died. Tom rushes to the Chamber just in time to see Harry regain a heartbeat.

Also, Tom has to carve runes on himself to make the Horcrux, and since the ritual goes awry, they don't get healed.

Comment: Hi. Did you check these? https://www.reddit.com/r/HPfanfiction/comments/jhnmb5/time_travel_fics_where_harry_travels_back_to_toms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. It's [*Splinters*](https://archiveofourown.org/works/12250938/chapters/27837651) by Aquaphobe on AO3.

> Harry Potter steps onboard the Express with the skinless monster
> wailing in his arms. Its blood oozes out of open arteries and gathers
> in a puddle at his feet.
>
> The doors click shut and the engine roars. The Platform is left
> somewhere far behind them.
>
> For minutes, for days, for years the train moves onwards, never
> stopping and never slowing.
>
> Until, finally, it does.